# "On grounds of" vs. "on the grounds of"

Tags: articles, phrase-usage

Here's the sentence from Wall Street Journal:

> ...eight individuals have been deported *on grounds of* national security.

Instead of this, if one says,

> ...eight individuals have been deported *on the grounds of* national security.

Any difference?

Answer (score 8):

I can find [two rules](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/articles.htm) to define this :

> 1. No article is needed before abstract nouns used in a general sense.
>      2.Articles are not needed in more abstract expressions of situation like to/at sea, to/at/out of work, in/out of town, in/out of office, etc.

I have a feeling that your expression *on the grounds of* would fit in as an abstract expression, as *grounds* is an abstract idea, not literally the ground.

Thus, whether or not you have the definite article doesn't matter. The meaning doesn't change, and there's no difference.

Comment: The only difference to a reader is that "on the grounds of" could mean in a physical location, so there may be a slight mental jolt when they hit the words "national security". Omitting "the" eliminates this since "the" is required in phrases like "on the grounds of the National Mall".

Answer (score 6):

A Google Ngram charting the phrases "on grounds of national" (blue line) versus "on the grounds of national" (red line) shows that both phrasings have regularly appeared in published writing for more than a century, with "on grounds of national" holding a significant (though recently lessening) advantage since 1913:

[image]

That record of usage strongly suggests that both forms are widely accepted, and I don't detect any difference in sense between them. (As an aside, I checked many of the underlying Ngram Books matches to see whether "on the grounds of national" might be enjoying inflated results owing to instances of phrases like "on the grounds of national parks"—but I didn't encounter any such complicating results; the nouns associated with both search phrases were consistently such words as *interest*, *policy*, *security*, *defense*, *origin*, and *unity*.)

Comment: A separate issue regarding "grounds" in the sense of "basis" involves the question of whether "ground" (singular) or "grounds" (plural) is preferable. See "[on the grounds that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236521/on-the-grounds-that)" for the relevant discussion.

Answer (score 1):

*...[E]ight individuals have been deported on grounds of national security* is correct. You can see the example sentence in Oxford advanced learner's dictionary.