# On the grounds that

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct: "on the grounds that" or "on the ground that" if only one 'ground' is given?

Comment: `on the grounds that` is probably going to sound more idiomatic, even though "on the ground that" could also be logically correct. You should probably write *on the grounds* on the ground that it will be easier to understand what you mean. But OTOH, it probably doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Yes. Use either, but be aware that _grounds_ is the more usual. From [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ground_1): _ground_ 8 _good reason_ [countable, usually plural] ground for something/for doing something; a good or true reason for saying, doing or believing something: _You have no grounds for complaint. // What were his grounds for wanting a divorce? // The case was dismissed on the grounds that there was not enough evidence. // He retired from the job on health grounds. // Employers cannot discriminate on grounds of age._

Comment: A related question involves use of the definite article before _grounds_; see ['on grounds of' vs 'on the grounds of'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39904/on-grounds-of-vs-on-the-grounds-of/39914#39914).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because April Fools.

Answer (score 5):

It's *possible* people in the legal profession may tend to prefer the singular form where there's only a single reason/justification, but I suspect the only reason we're more likely to encounter ***ground*** in such contexts is because "legalese" is a relatively conservative context.

In more general use, plural ***grounds*** became the more common form some decades ago, and I don't believe many "ordinary" speakers would ever stop to consider *how many* there might be...

[image]

Comment: This chart is nice but it doesn't make any consideration for whether the phrase that comes after "that" is actually plural or singular. Maybe we just gradually started thinking of multiple grounds on which to refuse someone, which would naturally cause "grounds" to become the standard. E.g. we usually ask "Do you have any **siblings**?" assuming more than one due to our expectations of family size, even though the addressed person may have only one sister or brother. But we ask "Do you have **a job**?", even though the person may have multiple jobs.

Comment: @Brandin: Gimmie a break! Are you seriously suggesting that usage might have changed so much because we're more likely to be talking about *multiple* reasons today than a century ago? My guess is in the vast majority of cases, only one "ground" is or ever was cited by the following text, but it would be irrelevant exactly what the ratio is, since there's no reason to suppose that would ever change significantly over time.

Comment: Yes, plural is more common than singular. If you think about it, there is only one case for singular to occur (the number "1"), wheras plural happens pretty much by default. BTW, another possibility for your chart is that the samples before 1970 simply had more singular examples, and post 1970 we have more plural examples. You'd really have to see what comes after "that" to say any more.

Comment: @Brandin: You seem to be just repeating the same (imho spurious) suggestion. I started my graph from 1900, but if you extend it back to, say, 1800, you'll see that the plural form was virtually unknown in the earlier century. Looking at the first page of *recent* instances for ***grounds***, I find 8 that unquestionably cite a *single* "ground". Both the other two effectively cite a single reason, but using syntax that might feasibly (but imho spuriously) be taken to imply two reasons (I think in both, the second element just "amplifies" on the point already made).

Comment: "Yes, plural is more common than singular. If you think about it," That's not really how frequencies work. For example, there are exponentially more firstborn children than second born. In any case, [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) how natural frequencies tend to work (irrespective of year).

Comment: @Parthian Shot: I'm not a statistician, but I know all about Benford's law, and I don't see how it relates to the matter under discussion. My gut feel is that *in the real world* when people talk about something being *on the ground[s] of some reason[s]* it's more likely there will only be *one* reason - but demonstrably it's more likely today to be referenced using "plural" *grounds*.